# How do I set up an event listener on a Hibernate 4 entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, listener

I'm using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE with Hibernate 4.0.1.Final.  I want to invoke an event listener on my entity bean when it is loaded from the DB, but I can't figure out what event I should be using.  I load my entities in my DAO like so

```
@Repository("eventFeedsDao")
public class EventFeedsDaoImpl implements EventFeedsDao {

    ...
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    ...

    @Override
    public EventFeed findById(final Integer id) { 
        EventFeed eventFeed = null;
        final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        final Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(EventFeed.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
        final List<EventFeed> results = crit.list();
        if (results != null && results.size() > 0) { 
            eventFeed = results.get(0);
        }   // if
        return eventFeed;       
    }   // findById
```

Here is how I'm trying to set up my event wiring ...

```
@Component
public class HibernateEventWiring {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private EventMavenLoadListener listener;

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerListeners() {
        EventListenerRegistry registry = ((SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory)
            .getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.LOAD).appendListener(listener);
    }
}
```

and my listener class is as follows ...

```
@Component
public class EventMavenLoadListener implements LoadEventListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onLoad(final LoadEvent event, final LoadType loadType) throws HibernateException {
        if(EventFeed.class.getName().equals(event.getEntityClassName())){
            EventFeed entity = (EventFeed) event.getInstanceToLoad();
            entity.setNetUtilsService(netUtilsService);
        }   // if
    }

}
```

but the "onLoad" event is never called.  What am I doing wrong?  Should I be using another event?

Answer (score 2):

For some reason that still eludes me, the EventType.PRE_LOAD event type was the way to go.  This worked.

```
@Component
public class HibernateEventWiring {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private EventMavenLoadListener listener;

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerListeners() {
        final EventListenerRegistry registry = ((SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory)
                .getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PRE_LOAD)
                .appendListener((PreLoadEventListener) listener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The load event is only triggered when loading an entity individually (session.get, initializing a proxy, fetching eager to-one associations).

The pre and post load events however follow JPA defined behavior and occur before and after the entity data is loaded regardless of how that "data load" occurred.

Its a case of bad name collision.

The preferred way in Hibernate 4, btw, to specify event listeners is through the use of an org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator.  See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/#integrators

Comment: With regards to the integrator, why is this better than the event wiring class I found?  I assume I have to annotate the integrator class with a "@Component"?  Thanks for the suggestion, -

Comment: Integrators can be discoverable via the JDK ServiceLoader class/pattern.  Which makes it much (much much) more easily usable in situations where you do not control the SessionFactory building (Spring, JPA, etc).  Do you mean @Component for discovery purposes?  If so, no, its discovery is via ServiceLoader as I mentioned.  It is covered in the docs I linked above, although you have to go to the linked section http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/#services-IntegratorService